# Moving Part of an SQL String into Another Variable

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a problem with a project with an sql function:

```
DECLARE @Var1 varchar(8000) = '{strong} this is strong{/strong} this is not strong.';

DECLARE @Var2 varchar(8000)
```

If I want to move the string between `'{strong}'` and `'{/strong}'` to `@Var2` to have this result

```
@Var1 = 'this is not strong.' 
@Var2 = '{strong} this is strong {/strong}'
```

How should I do it??

PS: I'm still new to sql :(

Thank you

Comment: Database? (I suspect MS SQL Server, but still)

Comment: Why did you use the SQL tag?

Comment: no strong is just a word a string nothing specific and yes MS SQL DB

Comment: If you define the variable yourself why don't you split it up from the beginning?

Comment: @fragmentedreality - It might be a function parameter in reality. I added the `DECLARE` to make things easier to follow.

Comment: @user2028521 - Does each possible input string only have one `{strong}...{/strong}` section? Is it always at the beginning?

Comment: Here's what I'm trying to do:

I'm making a windows form application and I'm using a richtextbox to export HTML to the SQL to be later imported into an htmltextbox in the reporter.
The problem is that the reporter can't read this kind of HTML, so I need to make a function that will simplify it to be able to print it later.
so i'm stuck on this part.

Answer (score 2):

Try the below Query... it will help you....

```
declare @var1 varchar(8000)
declare @var2 varchar(8000)
set @var1 ='{strong} this is strong{/strong} this is not strong.'
select @var2 = substring(@var1,charindex('{strong}',@var1)+len('{strong}'),charindex('{/strong}',@var1)-charindex('{strong}',@var1)-len('{strong}'))
SET @var1 = REPLACE(@var1,'{strong}' + @var2 + '{/strong}','')
select @var1 as Var1,@var2 as Var2
```

Answer (score 0):

Sql is not the best choice of place to do something like this

If I had to, like someone had a gun pointed at my kids

I'd do something like this, might need adjusting for your chose flavour of sql

This is T-SQL

```
Declare v1 VarChar(255)
Declare v2 VarChar(255)


set v1 = '{Strong}$REPLACE${/Strong}'
set v2 = 'This is strong'

Select Replace(v1,'$REPLACE$',v2)
```

The other way you would have to do something like use CharIndex to find '}{/'
Then use Substring to chop up V1 (as '{Strong}{/Strong}') and then concatenate them with v2

Answer (score 0):

Using `LEFT`, `RIGHT` and `CHARINDEX` as;

```
declare @start varchar(50)='{strong}', @end varchar(50)='{/strong}' 

select @var2 = left(@var1,charindex(@end,@var1,1)+len(@end)), 
       @var1= right(@var1,len(@var1)-(charindex(@end,@var1,1)+len(@end)))
```

[SQL DEMO 1](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/8322)

This is bit crazy but generic and works with some text `before '{strong}' tag` as well.

```
declare 
@var1 varchar(100)= 'front text{strong} this is strong{/strong} this is not strong', 
@var2 varchar(100)= ''

declare @start varchar(50)='{strong}', @end varchar(50)='{/strong}' 

select @var2 = substring(myString,ci1,ci2+len(@end)-ci1), 
       @var1 = right(myString,len(myString) - (ci2+ len(@end)))
from (
    select @var1 myString, charindex(@start,@var1,1) ci1, 
           charindex(@end,@var1,charindex(@start,@var1,1)) ci2
) T  

select @var2 var2 ,@var1 var1
```

[SQL DEMO 2](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/8311)

```
--Results
VAR2                                VAR1
{strong} this is strong{/strong}    this is not strong
```